# How to get filename in Typo3 solr extension with FAL and own Extbase extension

Tags: solr, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, fal

Before FAL, I can get the filename of an image from my own Extbase extension in the `solr` config file "typo3/ext/solr/Configuration/TypoScript/Solr/setup.txt" via

```
index {
    queue {
        tx_myextension = 1
        tx_myextension {
            fields {
                ...
                myimage_stringS = articleimage
                ...
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Where "articleimage" was a database field with the image filename. But since FAL, in "articleimage" is only a "1" saved, and the filename is gone to any of the sys_* tables.

I wonder how to get the filename inside the `solr` Extension -> `setup.txt` file?

Using `solr` Extension V3.0.0 on Typo3 V6.2 with SolR 4.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution found:

```
index {
    queue {
        tx_myextension = 1
        tx_myextension {
            fields {
                ...
                bild_stringS = FILES
                bild_stringS {
                        references {
                                  table=tx_myextension_model_name
                                  uid.data = field:uid
                                  fieldName=artikelbild
                        }
                        renderObj = TEXT
                        renderObj {
                                  stdWrap.data = file:current:publicUrl
                                  stdWrap.wrap = |
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I get the URL, which can be put out in a `solr` Template.